# Custom Show instance for Complex

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to print complex numbers like this:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Complex a) where
    show (a :+ b) = show a ++ " ":show b ++ "i"
```

But the module is `deriving(Show)` for `Complex`. I could copy the `Data.Complex` module, remove the `deriving(Show)` part and add my own instance or before printing I could map all complex numbers to a custom type which can only print complex numbers but doesn't care about doing math with them but this is annoying when you have complex numbers somewhere hidden in a tree or so. Are there better solutions to this? For example an extension that lets you override derived instances?

Comment: I would do either: wrap it `newtype MyComplex a = Complex a` or write another function `show'` - everything besides seems a bit harsh

Comment: The problem with newtype is that I would have to add instances for all the math stuff.

Comment: @1213 `newtype` allows to automatically derive instances provided by the type you are wrapping.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that ^^ doesn't seem so inconvenient anymore.

Comment: You add `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` and then you can write `newtype MyComplex a = MyComplex (Complex a) deriving (Eq, Num, Fractional, Floating)`.